# MATLAB fminunc lsqnonlin force number of iterations

Tags: matlab

Could you help me on how to set options for the fminunc or lsqnonlin optimizers, in such a way as to force them to do more iterations regardless of what internal tolerances they have ?

It seem that my loss is diminishing but the functions stop prematurely.

I have a code like:

```
options = optimset('Display','iter','PlotFcns',@optimplotfval)
options.MaxIterations=1e6;
options.CheckGradients=true;
options.FunctionTolerance= 1e-100;
options.OptimalityTolerance=1e-100;
options.StepTolerance =1e-100;

[xsol,fval]=fminunc(@myFun,x0,options);
```

I tried to put extremely low tol values... but this is strange... ideallly is there a way to say: "do your 1 million iterations regardless of anything else!"

Comment: Please add a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The optimization will terminate if any of the stopping criteria are sasified. Thus, you will have to **increase** the tolerances, e.g. to `Inf` to make them obsolete and leave the `MaxIterations` to be the single remaining criterion.